# Who is teacher of Lord Ganesha?

Tags: ganesha, guru

It has been observed that great deities have greater teachers (gurus). For Example, Lord Sun is teacher of Lord Hanuman. Similarly, I am curious to know that who is teacher/ are teachers of Lord Ganesha?

Comment: Ganesha ate the Gyana Mango and became Gnani if I remember where Narada muni brings and competition is there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guru Sakshath Parabrahma. 
Ganesha’s teacher is Parabrahman himself. I thought this was from Ganesh Purana but looks like I did see it one episode of the untold stories of Ganesh in the Hindi mythological serial 'Vignahartha Ganesh'. There are no references to this in the scriptures AFAIK. However, it is true that Ganesha’s Kundalini awakening and subsequent raise of Kundalini to Sahasrara Chakra was directly done by Parabrahman. This is through word of mouth from known Pandits. Since it was taught by PB to Ganesha he stands as the Guardian of all Kundalini awakening paths and helps aspirants. Symbolically, One could relate how he stands guard while Parvati the consort of Shiva was bathing.  Kundalini is nothing but Moola prakriti or Parvati. One of the prominent South Indian female saint called Avvayar has written something called ‘Agaval’  or ‘Vinayagar Agaval’ here http://www.alchemywebsite.com/vinayaga.html Which talks about how Ganesha helped her raise her Kundalini. The translation is very interesting. Since PB directly taught Ganesha none of the Trimurtis or their Consorts or others know what he Knows. Much like Dakshinamurthy’s silent teaching to Santa kumara brothers who were Brahma’s sons. No scriptures expound what he taught. Similarly, Ganesha always knows more and helps out if you please Him is the popular belief...

Comment: Hello Gopal! Welcome to HSE! Whenever you are answering a quetion, you must include sources and citations, so that it becomes more clear... 

Comment: I am looking for cited source...